# Significance of having closed range for an operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question

One thing I think is of great importance is that it seems to correspond to possibilities similar to rank nullity theorem and further the fredholm alternative much as in finite dimension.

Is this a correct observation and are there other direct significant consequences to having closed range or not having it?

Some literature and comments regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a closed range is (in the sense below) equivalent to bounded invertibility:
Let us assume that $X,Y$ are Banach spaces and that $T : X \to Y$ is linear, bounded and injective. Now, we restrict the codomain of $T$ to the range, i.e., we consider $T : X \to \mathcal{R}(T)$. Then, $T$ is invertible. Moreover, the boundedness of $T^{-1} : \mathcal{R}(T) \to X$ is equivalent to the closedness of $\mathcal{R}(T)$. This follows easily by the bounded inverse theorem.

If $T$ is not injective, the same reasoning can be used for
$$\tilde T : X / \operatorname{ker}(T) \to Y,$$
which maps an equivalence class $[x] \in X / \operatorname{ker}(T)$ to $T\,x$.

Comment: Very nice, I suppose the rank-nullity analogy is that $R(\tilde T)$ has to be closed to have the above isomophism, further should it be $R(\tilde T)$ and not Y in your above equation?

Comment: Yes, $\tilde T : X / \operatorname{ker}(T) \to \mathcal{R}(T)$ is always invertible. Note that $\mathcal{R}(T) = \mathcal{R}(\tilde T)$.